# Unable to launch byobu with custom windows.NAME file

Tags: byobu

Apologies if the solution is obvious but I'm stumped!

I want to launch byobu from within my Gnome 3 desktop environment on 12.04 but it's not working for me as yet. Here's what I have:

created a windows list file ~/.byobu/windows.mrb
then tried to launch byobu from within the gnome terminal with:

```
$ BYOBU_WINDOWS=mrb byobu
```

But it gives me the default windows list, NOT my windows list. I followed these instructions from the wiki: 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Byobu#Window_Sets

Here is a sanitised version of my windows.mrb file:

```
    screen -t local bash
    screen -t name1 ssh xxx@xxx
    screen -t name2 ssh root@xxx
    screen -t name3 bash
```

Appreciate the time and effort.

Cheers
Brendan

Answer (score 0):

Update your byobu to the latest version.  I didn't find any documentation stating when this config became available, but I've been bitten by it twice.

Each time I have to manually checkout the source code, compile and install the latest version.  All of a sudden, all windows config works.